# Consistently update page with appropriate jQuery Mobile styles

Tags: jquery, templates, mobile-website, jquery-mobile

I have a list of items with which I would like to view more details of them when I click on it.  The information for these items isn't available and I need to make an API request in order to get the necessary data which I then render in a jquery template.

The template is then added to a jquery mobile page.

Here is some of the code in question that I am using to try and update my page

```
function updateProductDetails(data){
    var productDetailsData = data['product']
    var productDetailsPage = $("#productDetails")

    var templateData = $("#productDetailsTmpl").tmpl(productDetailsData);

    productDetailsPage.html(templateData);

    //ISSUE IS HERE -- The following works when I load a template
    // for the first time, after that it doesn't work as expected.
    productDetailsPage.page();

    $.mobile.changePage("#productDetails");
}

function loadProductDetails(productId){
    $.mobile.pageLoading();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/admin/products/'+productId+".json",
        success: function(data, status, xhr){
            updateProductDetails(data);
            $.mobile.pageLoading(true);
        },
        dataType: 'json'
    });
}

$("#productItem").live('click', function(event){
    var productId = $(this).children("#productId")[0].innerHTML;
    loadProductDetails(productId);
});
```

The following is the div I use for the product details as well as the template for which I use to populate that div

```
<div id="productDetails" data-role="page">
</div>

<!-- Product Item Details Template -->
<script id="productDetailsTmpl" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>${title}</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
        <h1>Properties</h1>
        <p>${product_type}</p>
        <p>${vendor}</p>
    </div>
</script>
```

Here is a screenshot of a details page when I first click on an item:

[Details page working](http://cl.ly/2u0J0Y3O0a0M2e0w3y1T)

[Details page not working](http://cl.ly/1D1G1C0c1g1M2C2i0y0C)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to tell the page to refresh itself the second time around. First time it creates everything and then doesn't go around re-styling itself. I had a similar issue dynamically creating LIs in a listview.

Try:

```
productDetailsPage.page("refresh",true);
```

Not sure if this will work the first time around, but it should for the 2nd :)

Comment: That does work sometimes, but I found the way to get it to consistently work was to call listview() on the item which would make jquery go in and apply all the necessary styles to it.

Comment: Yeah, I actually do it on the listview too, but I wasn't sure if you were creating stuff outside the listview too.