# Forcing jQuery Mobile to re-evaluate styles/theme on dynamically inserted content

Tags: jquery-mobile

**Objective:**   Load HTML content via `$.ajax`, insert it into the DOM, have jQuery Mobile apply theme styles to it.

**Problem:**   Content gets inserted but lacks jQuery Mobile theming.

**Code:**

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    success: function(html) {
        $('#container').append(html);
        $('#page').page('refresh', true);
    }
});
```

The HTML returned includes `data-role` tags which jQM should style...

```
<a data-role="button">Do Something</a>
```

Instead of applying the styles like it should, I get the following error:

> uncaught exception: no such method
>   'refresh' for page widget instance

---

Above code tested using `http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.js`

---

Similar questions which brought me to the above error message:

[Consistently update page with appropriate jQuery Mobile styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157386/consistently-update-page-with-appropriate-jquery-mobile-styles)

[JQM (jQueryMobile) Dynamically added elements not displaying correctly and CSS is not applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5249250/jqm-jquerymobile-dynamically-added-elements-not-displaying-correctly-and-css-is)

[jQuery Mobile - Dynamically creating form elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4039428/jquery-mobile-dynamically-creating-form-elements)

Comment: I tried adding the .trigger("create") JS at the end of the document I wanted to load; and it worked great.

Answer (score 66):

Just got an answer to a similar question, try using

```
.trigger("create")
```

on the element that gets the content added to.

See here: [jQuery Mobile does not apply styles after dynamically adding content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999436/jquery-mobile-does-not-apply-styles-after-dynamically-adding-content)

Comment: This works for me, as of the date of this comment, where .page() doesn't always do the trick.

Comment: I had to move up a level to get it working properly - so I called the trigger on the div above the listview that I had injected. Thanks for this, I spent half a day messing around with .listview without success

Comment: This works, but has been [deprecated as of jQuery 1.4](http://jquerymobile.com/upgrade-guide/1.4/#enhancewithin).  Use .enhanceWithin() intstead.

Answer (score 12):

If you add items to a listview, you'll need to call the refresh() method on it to update the styles and create any nested lists that are added. For example:

```
$('#mylist').listview('refresh');
```

If you need to render a dynamic page, please read:"[jQuery Mobile and Dynamic Page Generation](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-dynamic.html)". Sample code from this article:

```
// Load the data for a specific category, based on
// the URL passed in. Generate markup for the items in the
// category, inject it into an embedded page, and then make
// that page the current active page.
function showCategory( urlObj, options )
{
    var categoryName = urlObj.hash.replace( /.*category=/, "" ),

        // Get the object that represents the category we
        // are interested in. Note, that at this point we could
        // instead fire off an ajax request to fetch the data, but
        // for the purposes of this sample, it's already in memory.
        category = categoryData[ categoryName ],

        // The pages we use to display our content are already in
        // the DOM. The id of the page we are going to write our
        // content into is specified in the hash before the '?'.
        pageSelector = urlObj.hash.replace( /\?.*$/, "" );

    if ( category ) {
        // Get the page we are going to dump our content into.
        var $page = $( pageSelector ),

            // Get the header for the page.
            $header = $page.children( ":jqmData(role=header)" ),

            // Get the content area element for the page.
            $content = $page.children( ":jqmData(role=content)" ),

            // The markup we are going to inject into the content
            // area of the page.
            markup = "<p>" + category.description + "</p><ul data-role='listview' data-inset='true'>",

            // The array of items for this category.
            cItems = category.items,

            // The number of items in the category.
            numItems = cItems.length;

        // Generate a list item for each item in the category
        // and add it to our markup.
        for ( var i = 0; i < numItems; i++ ) {
            markup += "<li>" + cItems[i].name + "</li>";
        }
        markup += "</ul>";

        // Find the h1 element in our header and inject the name of
        // the category into it.
        $header.find( "h1" ).html( category.name );

        // Inject the category items markup into the content element.
        $content.html( markup );

        // Pages are lazily enhanced. We call page() on the page
        // element to make sure it is always enhanced before we
        // attempt to enhance the listview markup we just injected.
        // Subsequent calls to page() are ignored since a page/widget
        // can only be enhanced once.
        $page.page();

        // Enhance the listview we just injected.
        $content.find( ":jqmData(role=listview)" ).listview();

        // We don't want the data-url of the page we just modified
        // to be the url that shows up in the browser's location field,
        // so set the dataUrl option to the URL for the category
        // we just loaded.
        options.dataUrl = urlObj.href;

        // Now call changePage() and tell it to switch to
        // the page we just modified.
        $.mobile.changePage( $page, options );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

If you're using the ajax method to load into content, this is how I got the styling and jquery mobile functionality to work.  It's pretty much the same as the suggestion above but for some people you probably like seeing a more full example.

Here is the code:

```
$.ajax({
url: 'url.php',
success: function(data) {    
$("#div").html(data).trigger('create');
}
});
```

Comment: this is the only example I've seen where the selector is not something like $('#myListView'), but the parent div. in my case my ul-listview was being returned from the ajax call and doing $("#div").html(data) would get the data but then calling .trigger on the listview wouldn't do anything. I wouldn't think to call $("#div").trigger('create'), but like your sample, seems to work. how odd. thanks! I spent hours on this.

Answer (score 4):

As an update to the answers provided. As of v1.45 you can select your content and use `.enhanceWithin()` to enhance the child elements.

http://api.jquerymobile.com/enhanceWithin/

Comment: This can be used after an asynchronous postback in ASP.Net, e.g. with an UpdatePanel.  It works beautifully.

Answer (score 1):

**In jQuery Mobile Framework alpha4.1 and earlier** this was done by using the `.page()` method.

Example to show there's not much of a difference:

```
$( ... lots of HTML ...).appendTo(".ui-content").page();
```

More info: http://jquerymobiledictionary.dyndns.org/faq.html

Why the new way (see T. Stone's answer) was introduced? `.page()` was written with an assumprion that the DOM element was not enhanced before.

For the sake of decoupling tje jQuery Mobile team introduces event-driven enhancement that will not only allow triggering the event, but also will make creating new widgets for new `data-role`s possible without modifying the code of JQM's .page method.

Answer (score 1):

`$('.selector').trigger('create');` seems to be the best approach, see the official FAQ below:

http://view.jquerymobile.com/master/demos/faq/injected-content-is-not-enhanced.php

Answer (score 0):

For others searching for an answer for this, as of 6/9/2011 the jQuery mobile team has implemented this feature in a development branch.  According to this issue, it will work in this manor:

`$(".ui-content").append( ... lots of HTML ...).trigger( "enhance" );`

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/1799

Comment: This is too soon. I understand you wanted to be the first to post about it, but the code was not yet released and you can cause a lot of confusion by not providing any information about a release that has this feature.