# JQuery Mobile Append new Buttons not behaving as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery Mobile does not apply styles after dynamically adding content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999436/jquery-mobile-does-not-apply-styles-after-dynamically-adding-content)

I'm wondering if I am missing something here...

If I write

```
<a onclick="deleteThis()" data-role="button" data-theme="a">Button text</a>
```

within the body of an HTML page it works fine. 
But when I programatically try and add new buttons using the following :

```
$('.block').append('<a onclick="deleteThis()" data-role="button" data-theme="a">' + results[i].Title + '</a>');
```

The link is appended fine just with no JQuery mobile styling, data-theme="a" should apply a particular colour swatch css to the element in question.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: When are you performing the append? I would try appending before any other JS code and see if this works.

Comment: Does jQuery mobile parse the html and style it accordingly after it's rendered?  If it is it would need to re-parse an element if it's added after the dom is loaded.  I'm not sure this is the case just curious.

Comment: Currently in $(document).ready

Comment: Sounds like that might be along the write lines but I too do not know how to do that.

Comment: @user1202278  Use $(document).bind('pageinit'), not $(document).ready() http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/api/events.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 $('.block').append(' <a onclick="deleteThis()" data-role="button" data-theme="a"> Text</a>').trigger( "create" );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.buttonMarkup()` method supplied by jQuery Mobile. This method allows you to pass some optional parameters as well.

Here are the docs for the `.buttonMarkup()` method: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/buttons/buttons-options.html

Here is an example of using this method to create a button:

```
$('<a href="#" />').text('New Button').buttonMarkup({
    theme  : 'a',
    icon   : 'star',
    mini   : false,
    inline : false
});
//these are just a few of the options
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/6BF6M/

Also, might I suggest using jQuery to make your event bindings, something like:

```
$('.block').append(
    $('<a href="#" />').text('New Button').buttonMarkup().bind('click', deleteThis)
);
```

Answer (score -1):

try triggering the refresh event, for a page:

```
$('#pageId').trigger('pagecreate');
```

if it's a listview:

```
$('#listId').listview('refresh');
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that with no success unfortunately

Comment: what's the structure of your html?

Comment: I've got a simple mobile layout on the go. Onload of the page I have javascript querying an external api to retrieve some information to then display in a series of links styled like buttons. The data retrieval from the api works fine and is appended fine just with no styling.

Comment: @user1202278 are you sure? i just tried this, and theme was applied to the dinamically created button. Just call ('pagecreate') after the append

Comment: Yup, but calling .trigger( "create" ) after the append worked fine