# AngularJS + jQuery Mobile w/ No Adapter & Disabled Routing - Used For UI Styling Only

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, angularjs

I am learning AngularJS and have built a small application. Now that it's functionally complete, I'd like to style it up using jQuery Mobile.

Originally I dropped in [tigbro's jquery-mobile-angular-adapter](https://github.com/tigbro/jquery-mobile-angular-adapter), but ultimately decided it was more complicated and involved than I needed. I'm not after any fancy screen transitions or page management features in jQuery Mobile - I just want to use it for styling the application and let AngularJS handle the rest.

I read [this post](http://coenraets.org/blog/2012/03/using-backbone-js-with-jquery-mobile/), which has the same goal in mind, albeit with another framework, and contains a code snippet to disable the jQuery Mobile routing.

I've applied that snippet to my application in this order of script loading, just before the close body tag:

1. jQuery
2. snippet
3. jQuery Mobile
4. AngularJS

This snippet placement is the only one that works, or somewhat works anyway, in that anything in my index loads styled properly (header and main nav, basically), and my AngularJS routes work just fine, but any dynamically loaded templates that populate my ng-view, despite having jQuery Mobile data-roles (ul as listview, etc.), are not styled by jQuery Mobile; they're just plain HTML.

Does anyone have an idea as to how I could get those dynamically loaded templates to also be styled?

My index HTML structure looks like this:

```
<body>
    <div data-role="page">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
            <h1>MyApp</h1>
                <a href="#/home">Home</a>
            <a href="#/add_item">Add</a>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content" ng-view></div>
    </div>
    <!-- Scripts -->
</body>
```

And here's an example of one of my templates:

```
<ul data-role="listview" ng-controller="MyListCtrl">
    <li ng:repeat="item in things">
        <a href="#/item/{{ item.ID }}">{{ item.title }}<br/>{{ formatDateForDisplay(item.addDate) }}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Thank you!

Comment: could you provide sample of one of your templates?

Comment: This might get you at least some of the way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999436/jquery-mobile-does-not-apply-styles-after-dynamically-adding-content

Comment: Thankyou so much for this; I have wasted days trying to style an app with various frameworks and UI kits, and I actually started with JQM but gave up when it conflicted with AngularJS. Triggering create on the view div on ajaxComplete works well

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I ended up putting together this directive:

```
angular.module('myApp.directives', []).
    directive('applyJqMobile', function() {
        return function($scope, el) {
            setTimeout(function(){$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', el.trigger("create"))},1);
        }
    });
```

Then inside of each template, wrap the template content in a div and apply the directive there, i.e.:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController" apply-jq-mobile>
<!-- Template Content to be jQ Mobilezed -->
</div>
```

This works, but because of the setTimeout, the content flashes for a split second when loading. I'm still working on figuring how how to get rid of the flash.

To note, *without* the setTimeout in place, the data-role="listview" wouldn't be styled (I'm guessing since it had to be populated by ng-repeat still), but any static content in the view *was* styled.

Comment: Have you tried hiding the element until your `setTimeout` function runs?  Maybe `$(el).hide();` before your `setTimeout` line and then `$(el).show();` once you've called `.trigger()`.  Not sure if it will work, but it's worth a try.

Comment: Works well! I definitely had a "Duh! Why didn't I think of that!?" type reaction. Thank you very much, Noah!

Comment: If jQuery is loaded before Angular, `el` will be a wrapped jQuery element (rather than a jqLite wrapped element), so el.hide() should work.  I.e., there is no need to wrap it again: $(el) is not necessary.

Comment: Ok, this doesn't make sense at all. The `el.trigger` function is invoked inside the timeout, while the `$scope.$on` event is never triggered (otherwise there will be an error saying that the return value from `el.trigger()` is not a function. A better way (tested) would be to do: `$scope.$watch("$viewContentLoaded", function() {    el.parent().listview("refresh"); }); `, which incidentally does not need hiding and showing again, and does not flash.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, *el.trigger("create")* doesn't work for me. After looking at the angularjs-jqm-adapter, I found it uses *el.**parent()**.trigger("create")*, which it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty much working on the same thing (no jqm angular adapter). Here's my directive that gets triggered after the last element of the repeat:

```
Application.Directives.directive('jqmCollapsibleRepeat', function () {
  return function (scope, element, attrs) {
    if (scope.$last) {
        $(element).parent().trigger("create");
    }
  };
});
```

and here's part of my view that uses it:

```
<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true" data-transition="slide" ng-repeat="document in documents" jqm-collapsible-repeat>
    <h3>{{document.FileName}}</h3>
    ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me this worked:

html:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Suchen" data-inset="true">
    <li ng-repeat="alert in alerts" li-jq-mobile>
        {{name}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

js:

```
angular.module('alertList', [])
    .directive('liJqMobile', function() {
        return function($scope, el) {
            $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', el.parent().listview('refresh'));
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

for jqm pages and lists for me worked:

For pages:

```
<div applyjqmobile data-role="page" >
```

and for the list:

```
<li lijqmobile ng-repeat="aviso in avisos"  data-icon="false" >
```

And directives:

```
.directive('applyJqMobile', function() {
    return function($scope, el) {
        console.log('applyJqMobile');
        $(el).hide();
        setTimeout(function(){$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', el.parent().trigger("create"))},1);
        $(el).show();
    }
}).directive('liJqMobile', function() {
    return function($scope, el) {
      console.log('liJqMobile');
      $(el).hide();
      setTimeout(function(){ $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', el.parent().listview('refresh'))},1);
      $(el).show();
    }
})
```