# AngularJS ng-repeat alternative

Tags: angularjs, jquery-mobile

I'm new to angularjS.

I have angularJS working in parallel with jQuery Mobile.
In my case ng-repeat is not allowing JQM styles(specifically Slider Style), to get applied.
Just want to know is there an alternative for ng-repeat in angularJS to use.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you post a jsFiddle so we can see more specifically what you mean.  You should also search for using jQuery with Angular as this has been addressed many times.  Often setting up a directive will solve the issue.

Comment: Try to use this solution:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461426/angularjs-jquery-mobile-w-no-adapter-disabled-routing-used-for-ui-styling