# Having trouble using jquery mobile with underscore.js.

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, underscore.js

Hey guys I'm trying to use jquery mobile to build an app. Also using underscore.js for some templating features. I'm trying to figure out why the form doesn't take the css rules that come with jquery mobile. I think it has something to do with the fact that my form is inside a script tag for the use of underscore.js I hope someone can shed light on this issue.

```
<script type="text/html" id='usageList'>
 <form method="post" action="parse/final_template.html"> 
     <input type="text" name="Name" value="some text" data-mini="true" />
    <select name="Location">
     <% _.each(deals,function(item,key,list){ %>
    <% var f = item.Name; %><!-- create more variables -->

      <option value="<%= item.name %>">  <%= item.name %> </option>
    <% }); %>
    </select>


</form>
 </script>
```

Comment: Don't you have to bind all the jQuery mobile stuff when you add new things to the DOM?

Comment: @muistooshort how do I do that? Sorry kinda new to this.

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7999436/479863