# Change HTML content (jQuery Mobile)

Tags: html, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I am trying to change content of a div in html.
So I have this div with the id `contentindex` and I want to load the htmlsnippet from `offline/indexoffline.html` in there.

I tried to do it with `$load`like that:

```
$("#contentindex").load("offline/indexoffline.html", function() {
});
```

This correctly loads the content, but it doesn't show the content in jQuery css. So I have jQuery Mobile css and js in the head of my index and on the index it loads correctly, but as soon as I use this `$load` it dies..

I hope someone can help, I am really suffering on that. :(

Thank you!

Comment: The jQuery Mobile css. Well what I mean is that the next content I load in the div isn't applied with the jQuery Mobile stylesheet.

Comment: Now I understand. Well, this is the expected behavior and your question is a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999436/jquery-mobile-does-not-apply-styles-after-dynamically-adding-content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.trigger("create")` on new contents in jQuery mobile. It will enhance the elements using jQuery mobile css.

Comment: Thanks! Now I got the problem that the MY css isn't loaded correctly. :(