# Dynamic Dropdown Mobile Formatting

Tags: jquery

JQuery Mobile dropdown list is not formatting as a mobile look? I'm loading dynamic data via AJAX and dropdown retains its native look, however if I load static content via AJAX the formatting displays in MOBILE look.

HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="roster" data-add-back-btn="true">
    <div data-role="header" class="tb">
        <h1>Roster</h1>
        <a class="ui-btn-right" id="infoButton" onclick="openPickDate();">+</a>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content" data-theme="b" id="callback">  
      <!-- CONTENT LOADED VIA AJAX -->          
    </div>

    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div><!-- /footer -->
</div>
```

JQUERY:

```
$('#callback').append('<form><div data-role="fieldcontain" id="stations"></div></form>');      
$('#callback #stations').append('<select name="select-native-1" id="lol" onchange="ShowStations();">'+ KeyArray + '</select>');
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/yqZGW/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the same as the one described here: [jQuery Mobile does not apply styles after dynamically adding content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999436/jquery-mobile-does-not-apply-styles-after-dynamically-adding-content)

You have several possibilities to fix this problem, but the easiest one would be to add

```
.trigger('create');
```

to the modified element.

Your jQuery code will become:

```
$('#callback').append('<form><div data-role="fieldcontain" id="stations"></div></form>');      
$('#callback #stations').append('<select name="select-native-1" id="lol" onchange="ShowStations();">'+ KeyArray + '</select>');
$('#callback').trigger('create');
```

See the updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yqZGW/8/

Comment: Thanks, I had run into this once before but forgot the .trigger!