# how to make jQuery Mobile affect styles of newly created elements

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile

**Solution:**
This question has been asked and answered in another post:
[jQuery Mobile does not apply styles after dynamically adding content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999436/jquery-mobile-does-not-apply-styles-after-dynamically-adding-content)

**original question:**

I am using jQuery Mobile to design the UI of my app, it works on static html. For example, following code snippet would create a listview:

```
<ul data-role="listview">
    <li><a href="acura.html">Acura</a></li>
    <li><a href="audi.html">Audi</a></li>
    <li><a href="bmw.html">BMW</a></li>
</ul>
```

[image: listview created by jQuery Mobile]

But if that piece of html code is created and appended on the fly, you would not see the effect added by jQuery Mobile, how can I make it work?

Comment: `ul` is static or dynamic?

Comment: @Omar, it is dynamic. BTW, just found a solution in another post, will update this.

Comment: `$("#listviewID").listview();` that's all.