# using jQuery Mobile in Yii 2

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-mobile, yii, yii2

i'm a new Yii 2 develpoer !
i create a gridview like below :

```
<?php Pjax::begin()?>
    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider'   => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
            'id',
            'countrydate',
            'countryName'=>[
                'attribute'=>'countryName',
                'content' => function($model,$key,$index,$column) {
                      return Html::a(
                '<div data-role="main" class="ui-content">'
                   .'<a href="#myPopup'.$key.'" data-rel="popup" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all">'
                     .'<span id="countryNamevalue'.$key.'">'.$model->countryName.'</span>'
                   .'</a>'
                   .'<div data-role="popup" id="myPopup'.$key.'" class="ui-content">'
                     .'<h2 id="a'.$key.'">enter the new data</h2>'
                     .'<input id="myinput'.$key.'" type="text" >'
                     .'<button onclick=showcountryCode(myinput'.$key.'.value,'.$key.') >Submit</button>'
                   .'</div>'
                .'</div>'
                        ,null
                        ,$options = [
                        'id'=>'countryCode'.$key,
                        'style'=>['border'=>'none' , 'background'=>'none'],
                    ]);
                }
            ],
            'countryName',
            'countrydate',
            'population',
            'fipsCode',
        ],
    ]); ?>
    <?php Pjax::end()?>
```

as you can see i use jQuery Mobile in My php file in  `'countryName'` .
now this picture is my website  [Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9zcB.png)

but when i change the page my page will be somthing like this : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tfe8n.png)

as you can see all of the jQuery MObile line that were hidden suddenly show block in the new page and i have to refresh the page to fix this !!!

can anybody tell me what should i do to fix this ?

Comment: can you show us the JS you're running?

Comment: @D.Mill i did it , in my code line 13 !! , in line 13 i start JQuery Mobile !!!

Comment: I fail to see where you load the JS files or what they contain in your question. For instance where is `showcountryCode()` defined? Also I find it odd that you have divs and anchors all included inside an anchor. It's possible that this produces errors on some platforms as it is not html5 compliant

Comment: aha !!! `function showcountryName(name,id)
    {
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function  () {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                window.alert(this.responseText);
                document.getElementById("countryNamevalue"+id).innerHTML = name;
            }
        }`

Comment: and : `xmlhttp.open("GET","crudphp/editcountryName.php?q="+q+"&name="+name,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }`    the showcountryCode is showCounteryName i change the name this morning !!! @D.Mill

Comment: ok I'm starting to understand what the issue is here. What version of yii2-pjax do you have installed?

Comment: i really don't know the Version of Pjax !!!! i just add the Pjax Line into my code @D.Mill

Comment: You can find it by checking the composer.lock file

Comment: "name": "bower-asset/yii2-pjax",
            "version": "v2.0.6",
+++ "bower-asset/yii2-pjax": "~2.0.1", +++ @D.Mill

Comment: ok one last question. How to you bind the jquery mobile behaviors to `<div data-role="main" class="ui-content">` ? You must have some sort of onclick() JS to make the modal show? Or is this auto?

Comment: i don't use any onclick beacalus jQuery mobile did it auto @D.Mill

Comment: Mr @D.Mill Did You Figure out What is The Problem ???

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that jQuery mobile's "auto features" do not reload when you change content dynamically (via pjax for instance).

In order for this to work you will need to run `.enhanceWithin()` after every pjax success event. I suggest adding the following to your page JS (not column):

```
$(document).on('pjax:success', function(data, status, xhr, options){
   $('body').enhanceWithin();
})
```

For previous version of jQuery Mobile (< 1.4) use `.trigger('create')` instead of `.enhanceWithin()`.

See : [jQuery Mobile does not apply styles after dynamically adding content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999436/jquery-mobile-does-not-apply-styles-after-dynamically-adding-content)

Comment: i copy your code into my script tag , nothing happlend !!! did i do it in right way ?? @D.Mill

Comment: if you put an alert inside the function do you get an alerte when you change pages?