# listview won't inherit style when appending items via ajax.- Jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, mobile

i am trying to dynamically add items to a listview in jquery mobile via ajax.

When i return the data and append the generated html the new items don't inherit the listview style properties, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$(function() {
    $('.load_more').live("click",function() {
        var a_id = $(this).attr("id");
        var b_id = $(this).attr("data");
    if(a_id!='end'){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "data.php",
            data: "aid="+ a_id+"&bid="+b_id,
    beforeSend:  function() {
        $('a.load_more').html('<img src="loading.gif" />');

},
    success: function(html){
        $("#more").remove();
        $("ul#updates").append(html);
        $('ul#updates').listview('refresh');
        }
    });
}
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery Mobile does not automatically enhance dynamic content. You must trigger the `create` event to force jQM to initialize the new content:

```
$(html).trigger('create');
```

When it comes to listviews, the `refresh` should be sufficient when adding new items. See this example http://jsfiddle.net/qrYF7/.

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/pages/page-scripting.html

Similar questions:

[Forcing jQuery Mobile to re-evaluate styles/theme on dynamically inserted content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6297470/forcing-jquery-mobile-to-re-evaluate-styles-theme-on-dynamically-inserted-conten)

[jQuery Mobile does not apply styles after dynamically adding content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999436/jquery-mobile-does-not-apply-styles-after-dynamically-adding-content)

Comment: where exactly would i call that from, after an hour of googling thats what i came up with but tried and it never worked.

Comment: i tried that, $("ul#updates").append(html).trigger("create"); still doesnt work, thanks anyway

Comment: Perhaps your AJAX call is not returning what you think it is..? Calling refresh should be sufficient. See: http://jsfiddle.net/qrYF7/

Comment: i have no idea why your fiddle works and my code doesnt, my ajax is returning the proper data although im gettin an error now  TypeError: $("#updates").append(htmldat).listview is not a function

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar issues when making AJAX calls and have had no luck with listview() or trigger() functions. These work for me when the content is not dynamic, as in the jsfiddle in Derek's reply. What I have found though is that if you are using the google ajax API (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js -- or 1.7.1 or some variant) then the listview() function ceases to work in regards to style. When this script is added to the jsfiddle with static content, new items do not inherit style. If your page works without this script, removing it would be a temporary fix.