# Issue with LightSwitch restyling custom control with delayed rendering

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-lightswitch

I was playing around with a LightSwitch custom control using the simple code:

```
myapp.Facility_Details.ScreenContent_render = function (element, contentItem) {
    $(element).append("<ul><li><label><input type='checkbox'/><span>Test</span></li></ul>");
}
```

And I notice LightSwitch makes a valiant effort to rewrite my HTML after I render it, adding it's own control styling classes to the HTML and doing a bit of re-organizing. I figured I could live with this & just get used to what it did, but then I hit a worse issue when I added some AJAX to the mix. When I do my actual rendering in the `done` method of a `Promise` the post-processing doesn't happen.

EG:

```
myapp.Facility_Details.ScreenContent_render = function (element, contentItem) {
  contentItem.data.getCommodityGroups().done(function (data) {
    $(element).append("<ul><li><label><input type='checkbox'/><span>Test</span></li></ul>");
  });
}
```

Renders totally differently (Doesn't edit the HTML). I could live with this too, but then if I browse away from this page & back to it then it swaps over to the first display... I tried returning the Promise from render thinking maybe that'd let it wait for me to be done, but no dice.

Does anyone know how can I either:

a) Prevent this reprocessing so I get the HTML I write every time.

b) Trigger this reprocessing explicitly so I can make sure it happens after I render inside a Promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This restyling is coming from jQuery Mobile. Turns out the solution is to trigger a create event after editing the HTML (EG: `$(element).trigger('create');`) to tell jQuery Mobile there's new HTML to style.

Another approach is to add `data-role='none'` so jQuery Mobile leaves your HTML alone. I'll probably mostly use the latter, but it's good to know both exist.

Actually found the answer over at [another StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6297470/forcing-jquery-mobile-to-re-evaluate-styles-theme-on-dynamically-inserted-conten) - the trick was knowing it was jQuery Mobile that mattered which is a lot easier to find info for than LightSwitch itself.

Answer (score 2):

It is jQuery doing the work so wrap into jQuery object before appending it perhaps?
Look at the samples down the page here [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj733572.aspx#jquery).

Comment: I am already wrapping it in jQuery, that's what the $( around element is. `$(element).append` is a jQuery function. That said, noticing on that link that it's actually jQuery mobile styling lead me to find the actual answer by looking up jQuery Mobile's help so thanks :)