# Dynamically creating productlists with checkboxes in jQuery Mobile proves difficult

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile

I'm working on a mobile shopping list app that is supposed to support the user when creating shopping lists.

I use the Jquery Mobile framework to achieve mobile functionality easily.

This is my first ever web project with html and javascript.

I created a simple product list with checkboxes, Jquery mobile styles it automatically and it looks great immediately:

```
<form action="demoform.asp" id="list" method="post" name="list">
        <fieldset data-filter="true" data-input="#myFilter" data-role="controlgroup">
            <label for="0">Banane</label>
            <input id="0" name="products" type="checkbox">
            <label for="1">Gurke</label>
            <input id="1" name="products" type="checkbox">
            <label for="2">Brokkoli</label>
            <input id="2" name="products" type="checkbox">
            <label for="3">Chinakohl</label>
            <input id="3" name="products" type="checkbox">
            <label for="4">Grünkohl</label>
            <input id="4" name="products" type="checkbox">
            <label for="5">Eisbergsalat</label>
            <input id="5" name="products" type="checkbox">
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

I then wrote a javascript function that takes an array and writes the contents of the array in this format:

```
var options = [
        fruits = ['Banane','Gurke','Brokkoli','Chinakohl','Grünkohl','Eisbergsalat'],
        drinks = ['Wasser','Cola','Fanta','Sprite','Pils','Radler']
    ];

function makeUL(array) {
    // Create the list element:
    var list = document.createElement('fieldset');
    list.setAttribute("data-role", "controlgroup");
    list.setAttribute("data-filter","true");
    list.setAttribute("data-input","#myFilter");

    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        // Create the list item:
        var label = document.createElement('label');
        label.setAttribute("for",i);

        // Set its contents:
        label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(array[i]));

        // Add it to the list:
        list.appendChild(label);

        var input = document.createElement('input');
        input.setAttribute("type","checkbox");
        input.setAttribute("name","products");
        input.setAttribute("id",i);


        // Add it to the list:
        list.appendChild(input);
    }

    // Finally, return the constructed list:
    return list;
}

// Add the contents of options[0] to #productlist:
document.getElementById('productlist').appendChild(makeUL(options[0]));
```

#### I have encountered several problems related to my inexperience but this is the biggest one:

- JQuery Mobile takes the html I write and changes it significantly when the page is loaded. When I try to change the html after Jquery Mobile did its magic it looks unstyled. 
  I have to somehow tell Jquery Mobile to run its script for this particular element again. How do I achieve this, is there a better way in general when working with Jquery Mobile?

Comment: Yes it happens when using dynamic html.This question has some very good answers over [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6297470/forcing-jquery-mobile-to-re-evaluate-styles-theme-on-dynamically-inserted-content)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery Mobile is calling `controlgroup` an enhanced list of `checkbox inputs`.

So you need to empty the container of your set of checkbox inputs, add the desired items and then refresh the whole controlgroup:

```js
function makeUL(choice) {
  var cases = {
    "fruits": ['Banane', 'Gurke', 'Brokkoli', 'Chinakohl', 'Grünkohl', 'Eisbergsalat'],
    "drinks": ['Wasser', 'Cola', 'Fanta', 'Sprite', 'Pils', 'Radler']
  };
  var array = cases[choice],
    list = $("#list");
  list.controlgroup("container").empty();
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var item = $("<label for='checkbox-" + i + "'>" + array[i] + "</label><input type='checkbox' id='checkbox-" + i + "'></input>");
    list.controlgroup("container").append(item);
    $(item[1]).checkboxradio();
  }
  list.controlgroup("refresh");
}


$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page-1", function() {
  $("input[name*=radio-choice-wish]").click(function() {
    var wish = $("input[name*=radio-choice-wish]:checked").val();
    makeUL(wish);
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div data-role="page" id="page-1">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
      <h1>Shopping List</h1>
    </div>
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
      <div class="ui-field-contain">
      <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-mini="true">
        <legend>I wish...</legend>
        <input name="radio-choice-wish" id="radio-choice-wish-fruits" value="fruits" checked="checked" type="radio">
        <label for="radio-choice-wish-fruits">Fruits</label>
        <input name="radio-choice-wish" id="radio-choice-wish-drinks" value="drinks" type="radio">
        <label for="radio-choice-wish-drinks">Drinks</label>
      </fieldset>
      </div>
      <form action="demoform.asp" id="list-form" method="post" name="list-form">
        <fieldset data-filter="true" data-input="#myFilter" id="list" data-role="controlgroup">
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please, take a look also here: [Dynamic controlgroup](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/controlgroup-dynamic/)